# C++ : Problem when doing command line make : undefined reference for Singleton::theInstance

Tags: c++, makefile, reference, singleton, undefined

I am trying to create a Singleton class in C++.

Here is the error:

```
CMakeFiles/minisig.dir/src/main.cpp.o : Dans la fonction « main » :
main.cpp:(.text+0x9) : référence indéfinie vers « Singleton::theInstance() »
main.cpp:(.text+0x12) : référence indéfinie vers « Singleton::theInstance() »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/minisig.dir/build.make:155: recipe for target 'minisig' failed
make[2]: *** [minisig] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/minisig.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/minisig.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

For my code I just copy-pasted the code from this website: https://www.badprog.com/c-design-pattern-singleton
It seems that I can't reach "Singleton.cpp".
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you create the `singleton.h` and `singleton.cpp`? And remember to add them to your makefile so they are compiled with main.cpp?

Comment: My *guess* is that you don't build with `Singleton.cpp`.

Comment: thanks for your answer
I am sorry I am new to c++, how do you add a file to a makefile? 

I only did :
mkdir build/
cd build/
cmake .. /
make/

Comment: You have a `CMakeLists.txt` file somewhere where you list all the source files. You need to modify it to actually include *all* source file for your `add_executable` command in the file.

Comment: ok I guess I am just stupid, you are right I forgot to modify the CMakeLists, thank you very much, I know it is dumb but I spent my whole day on this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the answer was that I didn't change my CMakeLists.txt file before compiling
For next time :

- modify your file
- then command line : mkdir build, cd build, cmake .., make